# Synchronous Ajax request takes too much time. Asynchronous works partially

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I use the beforeunload event to trigger a page change and clear a "lock" on the current page. This will be deleted in the clearLock function in the change.php file. It works fine, when I change the pages. It also works when I close a tab, but it doesn't work when I close Firefox.

My solution was to make the request synchronous. Technically everything is okay und everything works. But about 60% of the response time of a page load is for waiting for the synchronous request. Further there are often freezes for a few seconds.

My request looks like that:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {

    var login_name=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']); ?>;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../libraries/change.php",
        data: {
            funct:  "clearLock",
            login:  login_name
        },
        async:false
    });
});
```

So is it possible to use an asynchronous request to trigger **beforeunload** on window close?

Comment: "So is it possible to use an asynchronous request to trigger beforeunload on window close?"  To trigger? What do you mean? You want instead to send a request when beforeunload event is fired, not the opposite, right? As i'm aware of, there is no relevant cross browser way of doing this

Comment: The users use Firefox only. As said, it worked fine with synchronous request. I want it to work with asynchronous, so that the response time of a page load is acceptable again.

Comment: And, unfortunately, FF is the worst to manage this kind of behaviour as i tested it in the past. The async request will be aborted once the document/page is unload. If i remember it well, this works in chrome but like i said, not in FF

Comment: So my options are switching the browser of the users or rather leave it synchronous?
Is there a way to make the synchronous request faster?

Comment: @A.Wolff That's terrible.  I've always assumed that asynch calls would be carried out, assuming that they're successfully passed to the server and then who cares if the client is still there.  Thanks for teaching me yet another valuable lesson :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-call-is-fail-on-window-onbeforeunload-event-in-firefox).

This way the Ajax call remains synchronous, but is only executed when someone is actually closing the site (close tab or browser with cursor). Might not work for keyboard shortcuts, but it works for most cases.

```
/*setup the variable that stores if mouse is outside the webpage*/
var userleaving = false;
/*mouse has left the body tag, assume person is moving mouse cursor to close the window/tab*/
$("body").mouseleave(function() { userleaving = true; });
/*mouse cursor back inside the webpage*/
$("body").mouseenter(function() { userleaving = false; });

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if(userleaving) {
        var login_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']); ?>;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../libraries/change.php",
            data: {
                funct:  "clearLock",
                login:  login_name
            },
            async:false
        });
        return void(0);
    }
});
```